# Does using "chflags hidden" generate file system events?

Tags: macos, filesystem

If a macOS application is using [file system events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events) to monitor files (and folders), will it receive notifications for changes caused by the user running `chflags hidden` and `chflags nohidden` on a file (or folder)?

(Searching for "hidden" in the Apple developer documentation linked above returns 0 results. The man page for `chflags` is silent on the topic, at least in macOS Ventura. My attempts to Google the answer have been unsuccessful.)